# Create AI in InnoDB like MyIsam

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

Example i have table :

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and if i insert like this:

```
NSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');
```

Than Return :

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

But this just for MyIsam, why we cant for InnoDB?, how to create that in InnoDB, I think we can using BEFORE INSERT for new ID, i dont know this work if my user more than 1000 user, My point is:

1. User insert
2. Before insert I checking LAST Primary
3. IF Null then i set 1, else NEW.ID + 1
4. Final, insert!.

I've done this benchmarking, but the result is not satisfactory. would work but some clients get error with my method, is there any other way / how?
Thank for Advance!

Comment: " is there any other way / how?" No using a trigger is the only way to simulate MyISAM groupwise auto increment.

Comment: You should check if you really need such a behaviour. Oftentimes, you realize it is just so that it "looks nicer". Then you will have to decide if that is worth getting errors (which do not have to be the end of the world if they happen rarely enough, as InnoDB allows you to just repeat it, since it supports transactions).